# Is there a certain size of the uniqid function?

Tags: php

I'm just wondering, does anyone know, whether uniqid function in PHP has a certain size? And If so, how many strings is it? I'm a bit confused as PHP manual says, that uniqid is 23 characters long when extended entropy used. But based on my observation, it varies between 26 to 28 characters.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this. Are you sure you're not providing a prefix when calling the `uniqid` function?

Comment: Care to tell us how you managed to get `uniqid` to return over 23 characters? Are we even talking about the native php `uniqid` function or something custom that emulates a GUID?

Comment: Oh, your right. I'm an idiot :]] What I used was: uniqid(rand(), TRUE); ......it works fine without rand() prefix. Thank you! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant confirm this behaviour:

```
php -r 'for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) print strlen(uniqid("", true)) . "\n";'
```

Tested on OS X and Ubuntu with PHP 5.3.x yields 23 on each iteration.

What os/PHP version are you using?

---

As the OP pointed out in the comments to his question: leaving out the prefix should fix the issue ;)

To elaborate a bit more, one can look at the PHP source code: https://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/tags/php_5_3_8/ext/standard/uniqid.c?view=markup at line 79:

```
spprintf(&uniqid, 0, "%s%08x%05x%.8F", prefix, sec, usec, php_combined_lcg(TSRMLS_C) * 10);
```

If no prefix is supplied and one looks up the definition of `php_combined_lcg` which returns a float with one leading decimal the output of `uniqid` should always be 23 chars long.

Comment: Do you have 32 or 64 bit php version? I mean actual php, not your OS.

Comment: @DmitriSnytkine which matters because of… ?

Comment: It's 32bit PHP 5.3.1. That was my fault, I used a rand function as a prefix, so based on what number was generated in rand function, prefix floated between 26 to 28 characters ;)

Comment: Ok, while we are on about uniqid function, let me ask you one more question - is uniqid function ideal for generating a salt string that is meant to be used in a hash function (hash_hmac etc. ;))?

Comment: @Ondrej if you use uniqid(mt_rand(), true) that would be sufficient I think. Then hash it with sha1 or the like.